# New term taxonomy and description in front page. Input's

Tags: php, taxonomy, terms, description, input

what's up guys.

In front page i'd like to make 2 text form input's to new term to a taxonomy and discription to this term.

I've got a code to add a new term

```
       wp_insert_term(
'Apple',   // the term         //Here i want value from input
'klient', // the taxonomy
array(
    'description' => 'A yummy apple.',   //Here i want value from input
    'slug'        => 'apple',
    'parent'      => $parent_term_id,
)
```

How can i do that? 
Plese help guys

Comment: How do you use this code?

Comment: After Submit button click, i want to make this code and save new term, and description data.
Could you help me?

Comment: Sure, but I don't know where and how you are using this code. Please add more details to your question by using the [edit](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/288684/edit) link under your question.